# Issue building cordapp example with gradle

Tags: gradle, corda

Building CordApp-example i got the following errors mark as fatal but the build is ok:

gradle build
:java-source:compileJava[Fatal Error] corda-confidential-identities-2.0.0.pom:51:6: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.

[Fatal Error] guava-21.0.pom:188:6: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.

[Fatal Error] artemis-pom-2.1.0.pom:1457:10: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

[Fatal Error] artemis-pom-2.1.0.pom:1457:10: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

[Fatal Error] jgroups-3.6.13.Final.pom:477:2: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

[Fatal Error] netty-parent-4.1.9.Final.pom:1283:10: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

[Fatal Error] genesis-default-flava-2.2.pom:388:6: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.

[Fatal Error] genesis-default-flava-2.2.pom:388:6: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.

[Fatal Error] objenesis-parent-2.2.pom:513:7: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

:java-source:processResources

:java-source:classes

:java-source:configureCordappFatJar[Fatal Error] corda-confidential-identities-2.0.0.pom:51:6: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.

.....

....

....

:kotlin-source:check
:kotlin-source:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2m 36s
14 actionable tasks: 14 executed

Comment: could you please add the link to the corda app example that you trying to build?

Comment: Also, can you tell us whether you're using the gradle wrapper (`gradlew`), or your own gradle installation, and which operating system you're using?

Comment: HIthe example is :https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example, with the jdk OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12) on redhat the errros does not appears otherwise in windows 10 with Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode) the errors are present

Comment: The errors comes eith both gradle and gradlew

Answer (score 0):

If the CorDapp Example runs fine on the machine after building, you can ignore this error. Please update the question if the nodes do not work as expected following the build.

Comment: Yes, as i wrote in the question the examles work, but i think it would be better to remove this errrors